# Automaticaly adding SDL dll to build/src, when SDL is compiled as a git submodule

Tags: cmake, dll

I've been working with SDL3 and I have a small inconvenience. When I want to launch my .exe file, I have to manually add `SDL3.dll` to the `build/src`. I want to somehow automate this process by adding it after compiling. The issue is that I use an interface with git submodules, so the `.dll` is not precompiled and you can not copy it with `file(<COPY|INSTALL> <files>... DESTINATION)`

My folder structure is as follows:

- build
- include
- src
- submodules

`submodules/CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(SDL)
add_subdirectory(glm)

add_library(submodules INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(submodules INTERFACE SDL3::SDL3 glm)
```

`src/CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
add_library(game SHARED game.cpp)
target_include_directories(game PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE main.cpp
engine.cpp
glad.c
graphics.cpp
action_manager.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE submodules game)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I added a CMake custom command to `src/CMakeLists.txt` [link to docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)

In my case it looks like this:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/submodules/SDL/SDL3.dll
                 $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
```